# Prove $\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{y^2+1}+\sqrt{z^2+1}\geq \sqrt{6x+6y+6z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove, that for all positive $x,y,z$ following inequality holds
> $$\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{y^2+1}+\sqrt{z^2+1}\geq \sqrt{6x+6y+6z}$$

I have attempted several approaches to prove this inequality, including using Jensen's inequality and various elementary inequalities like
$x^2+1\geq 2x$. However, none of these approaches led to the desired results. When using AM-GM inequality, I obtain a sixth root, which leads to nowhere.

Can someone provide me with hints or suggestions on how to approach this type of inequality?

Comment: You are posting the same question again.

Comment: I deleted previous one due to abnormalities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM, we have
$$\sqrt{(x^2 + 1)(y^2 + 1)}
= \sqrt{x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 1}
\ge \sqrt{x^2y^2 + 2xy + 1} = xy + 1.$$
Similarly, we have
$\sqrt{(y^2 + 1)(z^2 + 1)} \ge yz + 1$,
and $\sqrt{(z^2 + 1)(x^2 + 1)} \ge zx + 1$.
(*Note*: Alternatively, we may use the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality.)

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS}^2 &\ge x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 3
 + 2(xy + 1) + 2(yz + 1) + 2(zx + 1)\\
 &= (x + y + z)^2 + 9.
\end{align*}

Thus, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS}^2 - \mathrm{RHS}^2
\ge (x + y + z)^2 + 9 - (6x + 6y + 6z)
= (x + y + z - 3)^2 \ge 0.$$

We are done.

Comment: I have no one to help, but my question is closed and I don't know why my question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines? What is wrong with my question ? Please, don't send my external links with good question guide - I am convnced that my question satisfies these conditions!

Comment: @Darek Perhaps they want you to put more details  of your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Define the funtion $f(t)= \sqrt{t^2 +1}$ which is convex ($f''(t) >0$), apply the Jensen's inequality
$$f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \ge 3 f\left( \frac{x+y+z}{3}  \right)$$
and finally use the fact that
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}  \right)^2 +1} \ge \sqrt{2\cdot\frac{x+y+z}{3}}$$